# Accessing the data inside an class

Tags: php, class, private, elementor

if I echo `$this` inside `protected function _register_controls()` i get this as output

```
["data":"Elementor\Controls_Stack":private]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "866f5ae"
    ["settings"]=>
    array(13) {
      ["cggowl_field_gen"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(67) {
          ["field_type"]=>
          string(5) "title"
          ["title_typography_typography"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["title_typography_font_family"]=>
          ["_id"]=>
                string(7) "dd4a639"
```

how can i access the `["_id"]` at the last which returns `dd4a639`?

Comment: it has documentation ya know https://code.elementor.com/classes/elementor-controls_stack/

Comment: simply press `ctrl` + `f` and search `get_id`. its time to step up google fu. lol

Comment: @Ghost but it returns `866f5ae` instead of `dd4a639`

Comment: its inside settings, use get settings, play around

Comment: perfect thanks get_settings